# NiFi - Extract attributes from .tar files

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a workflow of several .tar files containing multiple csv files. After unpacking them through CompressContent and UnpackContent, I need to collect the attributes from the original .tar files. After the UnpackContent processor, I am currently sending the original files through the AttributesToCSV processor, where I overwrite the content of each file with the attributes in a csv format.

The main problem I am facing is that the file is a .tar, and even if I process it through CompressContent and UnpackContent again, it still remains in a .tar format.

Does anyone know a different way to extract attributes and have them in a csv file?
Thanks

Current Workflow:

1. CompressContent
2. UnpackContent
3. AttributestoCSV (flowfile-content)

Comment: i guess you want just rename file from `.tar` to `.csv`. use updateattribute to change `filename` attribute.